# QT Creator C++ not generating ui_.h file for one item

Tags: c++, qt

I've been working on my UI, and all that stuff compiles fine but I also wrote up the majority of my code then generated the header file for it part way through. But this header file will not compile - no errors. It just isn't in the build directory at all.

ink.h

```
#ifndef INK_H
#define INK_H

#include <QPaintDevice>

namespace Ui {
class Ink;
}

class Ink : public QPaintDevice
{

public:
    explicit Ink(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Ink();

private:
    Ui::Ink *ui;
};

#endif // INK_H
```

ink.cpp

```
#include "ink.h"

#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QPaintEvent>

void ink()
{


    QFile *brushInput; //takes raw 8 bit grayscale image, 8 bit values only
    char *brushProto;
    uchar *brushData;


    brushInput = new QFile("x:\\Development\\InkPuppet\\brush.raw"); //open the raw file
    brushInput->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    QDataStream in;
    in.setDevice(brushInput);
    int size = brushInput->size(); //set size to length of raw file

    brushProto = new char[size];
    in.readRawData(brushProto, size); //read file into prototype
    brushData = new uchar[size];

    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        brushData[i] = (uchar)brushProto[i]; //copy char to uchar array
    }

    QImage test(brushData, 128, 128, QImage::Format_Indexed8);
    QImage test2(128, 128, QImage::Format_ARGB32);

    QVector<QRgb> vectorColors(256); //create color table
    for(int c = 0; c < 256; c++)
    {
        vectorColors[c] = qRgb(c, c, c);
    }

    test.setColorTable(vectorColors);

    for(int iX = 0; iX < 100; ++iX)
    {
        for(int iY = 0; iY < 100; ++iY)
        {
            test2.setPixel(iX, iY, qRgba(255 - (qrand() % 100), 0 + (qrand() % 100), 0 + (qrand() % 100), qAbs((int)test.pixel(iX, iY)-255)));
        }
    }

    //final conversion for stencil and color brush
    QPixmap testPixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(test2);
    QPixmap testPixmap2 = QPixmap::fromImage(test);

    QPainter painter(this);

    painter.drawPixmap(150, 50, 100, 100, testPixmap);
    painter.drawPixmap(50, 50, 100, 100, testPixmap2);

    delete[] brushProto;
    delete[] brushData;
    delete brushInput;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "inkpuppet.h"
#include "ink.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    InkPuppet w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: You typically don't compile header files, you just `#include` them in files you *do* compile.

Comment: what do you mean? qt creator doesn't generate ui_file.h from file.ui? is this your problem? so what is ink.h? is this desired file but not being updated by qt designer?

Comment: I mean that the files for ink.h are not being compiled when I run the program

Comment: In the debug folder there is "moc_aboutdialog.cpp" & obj (from the aboutdialog files), "moc_inkpuppet.cpp" & obj but there is no moc.ink.cpp or obj or any files anywhere relating to them in the build

Comment: I "fixed" it by adding a new class/header and copying the code over. No clue what was wrong in my code, would love to know.

Comment: this is how you can generate .h file: uic CointegrationGUI.ui -o ui_CointegrationGUI.h.  I have many issues with QtCreator and almost always generate files this way because Creator doesn't updates them by itself, but I use strange configuration of IDE tools

Answer (score 3):

When you create a new form in QT creator you have to choose Qt Designer Form Class in order to generate the corresponding .cpp and .h files, otherwise it will only generate the .ui.

Comment: That may have helped, 3 years ago.

Comment: @Vii I've faced the same problem, and I solved that way. That's why I decided to post.